# .net onpaint vertical sync

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I'm trying to implement some animation using winforms and gdi+, but I get a lot of tearing moving sprites inside a control.

Is there a way in managed .net to have the overriden Control.OnPaint method wait for the vertical retrace of the monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Are you already using double buffering? If not I would suspect that would remove the tearing, and it is simpler than trying to wait for the vertical retrace.

Comment: Double buffering doesn't prevent tearing. See en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_tearing. Wait vsync is the only solution I know of in a Windows application. Unfortunately the only way I've found to do this involves Direct3D. Downloading a 500mb+ SDK just for one function seems a bit silly.

Comment: That's what I've found so far too. I guess GDI wasn't designed for animation.