# C# Screen flickers on Mouse Move

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, system.drawing

In [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) application, I am using a user control (named `panel`) and I am doing drawing on this panel.
However I have already used double buffering

```
public Panel()
{            
    //double-buffering
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
    SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true); 
}
```

But still when I fill any shape on my screen, screen flickers.

Also, I am doing number of calculations, which calculates the region to be filled  in the `Paint()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try turning resize redraw off

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819762/net-onpaint-vertical-sync

Comment: Can you show the code behind OnPaint() event?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you should not be doing it in the MouseMove event handler.  Double buffering can only work when you draw in OnPaint().

Comment: @HansPassant: actually i am using graphics.FillRegion(brush, graphics path) to fill a path of a shape. earlier when i wasn't using this method, screen wasn't flickering. i tried debugging, value of "nativeRegion" of Region i am filling is changing every time.

Comment: @HansPassant: does Double buffering works with Paint() ?? because i am overriding Paint() method and not "OnPaint()"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be useful. But I don't get any blink when I use `Invalidate` method and `OnPaint` event instead of `Paint` directly, (`DoubleBuffering = true`):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Graphics g = null;
    private Pen z = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Blue));

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        g = CreateGraphics();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(z, p, p2);
    }

    private Point p = new Point();
    private Point p2 = new Point();

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            p = e.Location;

        p2 = e.Location;

        Invalidate();
    }
}
```